# How to eliminate two instances of .exe compiled by PyInstaller

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller

I compiled a python program using [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). But when I execute the .exe file on a client, two instances of the .exe is running on the task manager.

[image]

How can i eliminate the other .exe? 
This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124603/pyinstaller-2-instances-of-my-cherrypy-app-exe-get-executed) didn't have any clear answer.

I'm using python 2.7 and I'm running the .exe on Windows XP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend reading this section:
https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#id74

Bootloader
The bootloader prepares everything for running Python code. It begins the setup and then returns itself in another process. This approach of using two processes allows a lot of flexibility and is used in all bundles except one-folder mode in Windows. **So do not be surprised if you will see your bundled app as two processes in your system task manager.**

Comment: thank you for this response, i opt to use other compiler.